# Lubuntu 14.04 black screen after decryption

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu, login-screen

I have several times installed and uninstalled VirtualBox, because Windows would not start. VirtualBox has been updated yesterday with the updates. Then I wanted to maintain the system and have executed the following commands:

```
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
apt-get update
apt-get remove texlive-*-doc
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*
sudo rm -rf /root/.local/share/Trash/*
```

After the restart, I can always decrypt the drive but then comes only a black screen. Actually, the user login should appear.
Many greetings